# C++ macro: absolute value?

Tags: c++, macros

dumb question. Just started using C++ macros, but can't understand what's wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define ABS(a) ((a < 0) ? (-a) : (a))

int main() {
    uint16_t a = 0xf0, b = 0xf8;
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << a - b <<" " << ABS(a - b) << endl;
    int c = a, d = b;
    cout << c << " " << d << " " << c - d << " " << ABS(c - d) << endl;
}
```

The output is following:

```
240 248 -8 -488
240 248 -8 -488
```

Tried with signed and unsigned, but the macro result is always the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have discovered one of the biggest reasons not to use macros. You know what `240 - 248` is; what happens when you put '-' in front of it?

Comment: Indeed, this should not be a macro to begin with. Why not making it a normal function?

Comment: @spectras or just `std::abs`

Comment: Macros are evil.  What is preventing somebody to use `ABS('&')` or ABS(std::vector<int>)?  Perfer to use library functions or inline functions.

Answer (score 5):

Let's take this macro:

```
#define ABS(a) ((a < 0) ? (-a) : (a))
```

And let's expand just this usage of this macro:

```
ABS(a - b)
```

If you go ahead and substitute verbatim (because that's how macros work) `a-b` everywhere `a` occurs in the macro, this is what you get:

```
((a-b < 0) ? (-a-b) : (a-b))
```

You can pretty much use your text editor's search/replace function to do this. The mistake is now glaringly obvious.

Your macro should be:

```
#define ABS(a) (((a) < 0) ? -(a) : (a))
```

(I threw in an extra set of parenthesis, just to avoid further trouble down the road).